# Execute a "DESC TABLE" command in Oracle using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

I need to find the column info for a number of Oracle views using JavaScript.  What I've tried is:

```
var conObj = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');     
conObj.Open(conString);     
sql = "DESC MyView";
rs1 = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

var commd = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Command');

commd.ActiveConnection = conObj; //

commd.CommandText = sql;

commd.CommandType = 1;

rs1 = commd.Execute();
```

What I get is an error about the sql statement.  I know the sql works in SQL Developer.

I can't use the alternative SELECT query as that returns an empty rowset - the view isn't populated when I need to run the query.  Only the DESC returns the values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is this code supposed to run? Where is the database server?

Comment: `DESC` is a `SQL*Plus` command. SO, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DESC` is a `SQL*Plus` command. SO, you cannot use it via JDBC/ODBC.
An alternative can be like this below.

```
select RPAD(COLUMN_NAME,30)||' '||DATA_TYPE||'('||DATA_LENGTH||')' as descr
FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('YOUR_TABLE') and owner=UPPER('SCHEMA_NAME');
```

[Oracle's Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)

`all_tab_cols` is a *data dictionary table*(view) which contains the table/view metadata.

**Example:**

```
SQL> create view MyView as select * from dual where 1=2;

View created.

SQL> select RPAD(COLUMN_NAME,30)||' '||DATA_TYPE||'('||DATA_LENGTH||')' as descr
  2  FROM all_tab_cols
  3   WHERE TABLE_NAME ='MYVIEW'  and owner='MYSCHEMA';


DESCR
------------------------------------------------
DUMMY                          VARCHAR2(1)
```

**Data and DESC**

```
SQL> select * from myview;

no rows selected

SQL> desc myview;

 Name       Null?    Type
 -----------------------------
 DUMMY               VARCHAR2(1)
```

Comment: I just tried plugging that in and it didn't like the FROM location.  I have tried : sql = "select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'mytable'" but that comes back empty.

Comment: The alias ,I chose was actually a reserved keyword,and hence it is. Try now please. Also, the table name has to be all _CAPS_

Comment: You could double quote the alias, "desc". Also, data_length is of type NUMBER (Oracle implicitly cast this as a varchar).

Comment: That gets past the problem with the FROM but it returns an empty rowset.  I think the problem there is that there aren't any rows in the view.  It isn't populated until later.  The DESC command does work - I assume it is using something deeper in Oracle.  When I run the DESC command I get a text string describing the table but I don't know how I would extract that.

Comment: @Patrick double quotes would work, but I personally dont use just because, while fetching I have to use the same case. (if I dont choose the column index). And type casting wont make an impact here I guess. But still user can include individual columns as well.

Comment: @user3772317 did you make the view name with CAPS, in the query ? No rows in the view, this query should still retrieve rows.

Comment: @user3772317 I have added a demo script. Kindly check on it.

Comment: I just ran this in SQL Developer and it came back as empty - select RPAD(COLUMN_NAME,30)||' '||DATA_TYPE||'('||DATA_LENGTH||')' as descr FROM all_tab_cols   WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('CALCOL') - CALCOL is the name of the view.

Comment: In SQL Developer, select the view name, and `Shift + F4 ` should open a pop up with describe. Does it happen ?

Comment: Nothing happens if I select the view and do a shift/F4.  The DESC works fine but the SELECT returns empty.  I just went through the list of views and found one that contains data.  The SELECT string you gave does return for that with data.  So it's only when the table isn't populated in advance that it fails.

Comment: where do you do the `DESC` ? In the demo of my answer, you can see, my view had no rows generated. Unfortunately your rep is too low for inviting to a chat.

Comment: I also just tested it in my JavaScript and it produced something I can work with. Thanks, that's closer. Now to figure out how to get the views that aren't populated.  Alas there are more of them than there are of the populated ones.

Comment: Glad about it. Kindly accept this as answer, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Maheswaran's query. Additionally, I tried the below query to get all the information. This lets me know about the different constraints and attributes.

select * 
FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE_NAME') and owner=UPPER('SCHEMA_NAME');